# Ito Process: How to calculate expected return?

Tags: options, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, geometric-brownian

On page 300 of Hull's *Options, Futures and Other Derivatives*

> It is tempting to suggest that a stock price follows a generalized Wiener process; that is, that it has a constant expected drift rate and a onstant variance rate. However, this model fails to capture a key aspect of stock prices. This is that the expected percentage return required by investors from a stock is independent of the stock’s price. If investors require a 14% per annum expected return when the stock price is $\\\$$ 10, then, ceteris paribus, they will also require a 14% per annum expected return when it is $50.

> Clearly, the assumption of constant expected drift rate is inappropriate and needs to be replaced by the assumption that the **expected return** (i.e., **expected drift** divided by the stock price) is constant. If $S$ is the stock price at time $t$, then the expected drift rate in $S$ should be assumed to be $\mu S$ for some constant parameter m. This means that in a short interval of time, $\Delta t$, the expected increase in S is $\mu S \Delta t$. The parameter m is the expected rate of return on the stock.

An Ito process can be written as $dx = a(x,t)dt + b(x,t)dz$, $dz$ is a basic Wiener process that has a drift rate of zero and a variance of $1.0$. I thought $a(x,t)$ is the drift of the Ito process $dx$, but after reading this, I know it is also the expected drift. Do we not need any calculation to get the expected drift of $dx$? If we need some calculation, how? Why does the expected return equal the expected drift divided by the stock price?

Comment: Under mild conditions (namely $\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t a(x,t)^2 dt \right] < \infty$), the process $\int_0^s a(x,t)dW$ is a martingale with mean 0. See this answer: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/15799/55385.